# differences from jovo v3 and v4

Tags: jovo-framework, javascript-decorators

in the v3 the handlers was registered with `app.setHandler`

```
app.setHandler({
 LAUNCH() {
  return this.toIntent('HelloWorldIntent');
 },

 HelloWorldIntent() {
  this.ask('Hello World! What\'s your name?', 'Please tell me your name.');
 },

 MyNameIsIntent() {
  this.tell('Hey ' + this.$inputs.name.value + ', nice to meet you!');
 },
```

in v4 (if i haven't understood well) are automatically registered with decorators? but how this meccanism works under the hood?
does someone can explain me tecnically?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, decorators are functions that take as arguments both the object they are decorating (for example, the component) and sometimes a set of options. The function can then modify the object using the options. This is a feature of TypeScript and not Jovo itself. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).